# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown

Tags: c#

My program throws this exception:

> System.StackOverflowException

when the compiler executes the set property.

The `wine` class:

```
class wine
{
    public int year;
    public string name;
    public static int no = 5;

    public wine(int x, string y)
    {
        year = x;
        name = y;
        no++;
    }

    public int price
    {
        get
        {
            return no * 5;
        }

        set
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Program` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wine w1 = new wine(1820, "Jack Daniels");

        Console.WriteLine("price is " + w1.price);
        w1.price = 90;
        Console.WriteLine(w1.price);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a backing field e.g. `private int _price` and then set that to the value e.g `set { _price = value; }`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When setting the price property, you invoke the setter, which invokes the setter which invokes the setter, etc..

Solution:

```
public int _price;
public int price
{
    get
    {
        return no * 5;
    }

    set
    {
        _price = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You're setting the value of the setter from within the setter. This is an infinite loop, hence the StackOverflowException.

You probably meant to use a backing field `no` as per your getter:

```
public int price
{
    get
    {
        return no * 5;
    }

    set
    {
        no = value/5;
    }
}
```

or perhaps use its own backing field.

```
private int _price;
public int price
{
    get
    {
        return _price;
    }

    set
    {
        _price = value;;
    }
}
```

However, if the latter is the case, you dont need the backing field at all, you can use an auto property:

```
public int price { get; set; } // same as above code!
```

(Side note: Properties should start with an uppercase - `Price` not `price`)

Answer (score 1):

Your property setter calls itself when you set any value, thus it produces an stack overflow, I think what you wanted to do was:

```
public int price
{
    get
    {
        return no * 5;
    }

    set
    {
        no = value / 5;
    }
}
```